# Is it possible that i can hide Image url so that user cannot see my uploaded image location?

Tags: html, image, url

[image]

When User inspect element on that image (apple.jpg) , he/she is able to see [image] or they could just right click on click on 'Copy image location and share that link with others. I dont want user to see this link . Or is it possible that we can encrypt that link??? so that 'Copy image location' is not possible , hence sharing that link is not possible.

Thanks,

Comment: By default, all the css, js , images  etc is shipped to client. I doubt if its possible.

Comment: EDIT : Hoijof's answer should do it.

Comment: You realise that the context menu has a 'save image' option, right? As do the web developer tools in the resources tab (in the browser's I've worked with).

Comment: i've no issue user saving those images. I got my answer thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can't hide where the client is loading the image from, but you can edit your server configuration so it [doesn't allow hotlinks](http://www.htaccesstools.com/hotlink-protection/)

Comment: The src tag has to be a valid url, since the browser will load it directly. If you encrypt it the browser won't be able to load the resource.

Comment: Of course it is, but then what? The shown URL has to successfully retrieve the linked file or image, and even if you hide it from the user it'll still be visible in the 'resources' tab of the browser's developer tools. What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish? If you don't want the the client to see/access the image, don't put it on the internet.

Comment: @DavidThomas okay got it , thanks buddy. I'm trying to show the image but doesnt allow user to share the pic .

Comment: @prabinbadyakar Remember that you can block hotlinks on your server so nobody can view the image even if they have the link.

Comment: @Hoijof thanks. dont know much about it, i wil so some research on them . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cant hide the url of the image as your code has to know where the image is stored. You could encrypt the url, but I think this is not possible with html itself.

I think, there was a tool doing exactly what you want, but I don't remember the name..